# AngularJS clear model when changing route

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a filter & search function in my fixed header consisting of dropdown (for filter) and input field (for search).

For the dropdown I'm using this [Angularjs-dropdown-multiselect](https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect)

At the moment, after submitting the request, user will be directed to result page and the model content for dropdown and input text is preserved and that's how I want it to be. The problem is, I want to reset the model (back to empty) if user go to page other than the result page.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="dropdown" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="cats" selected-model="catModel" checkboxes="true" translation-texts="{buttonDefaultText: 'Categories'}"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="dropdown" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="ccs" selected-model="ccModel" checkboxes="true" translation-texts="{buttonDefaultText: 'Credit Cards'}"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <form data-ng-submit="findValue(catModel, ccModel, keyword)" >
        <div class="input-group search-bar">
            <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." data-ng-model="keyword">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-search" type="button" data-ng-click="findValue(catModel, ccModel, keyword)"><img src="img/icon_search.png" alt="Search" /></button>
            </span>
            <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>
        </div>
    </form>                 
</div>
```

JS:

```
.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'dataFactory',
function ($scope, $http, $location, dataFactory){
    dataFactory.getCategories().success(function (data){
        $scope.cats = data;
    });

    dataFactory.getCcs().success(function (data){
        $scope.ccs = data;
    });
    $scope.catModel = [];
    $scope.ccModel = [];

    $scope.findValue = function(catModel, ccModel, keyword) {   
    var searchUrl = baseUrl;
    var catID = '';     
    if(catModel.length > 0) {
        searchUrl += 'categoryID=';
        angular.forEach(catModel, function(value, key) {
            if(key < catModel.length - 1) {
                searchUrl += value.id + ',';
                catID += value.id + ',';
            } else {
                searchUrl += value.id;
                catID += value.id;
            }
        })  
        if(ccModel.length > 0 | keyword != null) {
            searchUrl += '&';   
        }              
    } 

    if(ccModel.length > 0) {
        searchUrl += 'ccID=';
        angular.forEach(ccModel, function(value, key) {
            if(key < ccModel.length - 1) {
                searchUrl += value.id + ',';
            } else {
                searchUrl += value.id;
            }
        })
        if(keyword != null) {
            searchUrl += '&';
        }                
    } 

    if(keyword != null) {
        searchUrl += 'search_keyword=' + keyword; 
    }

    $http.get(searchUrl).success(function (data) {
        $scope.results = data;
        $scope.pageTitle = 'Promotions search result';
        $location.path('/promotion');
    })
}
}
```

I'm putting the model and function inside mainController because the header is in every view.

I'm quite new in AngularJS and programming so this code might not be proper, please let me know if there's a simpler and proper way. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: is `submit` redirect to another url?

Comment: Yes, it will redirect to result page with different view and different $location.path

Comment: then why dont you set `$scope.keyword==""` just before `$location.path`

Comment: That will clear the keyword at the result page as well. What I'm trying to do is preserve the keyword/model in result page, but if user navigate to other page, e.g. home page, the keyword will be cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to the following event `$locationChangeSuccess` that will be triggered on every location change. 
And inside you can reset your model.

Just declare

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
   //reset your model here
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean that the model must be in $rootScope?

Comment: I put some example of my code if you use your model only in the controller $scope you can put it on the controller's $scope